# Extensionbility of PEX

Tags: pex

I had gone thru Pex, [Extensions Writer Handbook](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/guidancepexextensions.pdf) but this document is just 5 page, and not elaborative. I need some more about extensibility.

I have gone to http://pex.codeplex.com/ which extends pex for different Testing Framework plus DySy and ASE extension. But, it was written again pex version 0.18 and current is 0.94.x. Many classes were refactored and changed. Hence, it can’t compile.

I am stuck on where, I need to extend the test method name creation according to my logic, Where should I start with? Is there any open source project available on web against pex 0.94.x which I could use for study and reference?

Comment: I'm interested in almost the same scenario..

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the handbook is not helpful
for changing the test method name creation i found this code on this blog http://tech.rofas.net/?tag=/code

```
class KeepOriginalTestNamesAttribute : PexTestNamerAttributeBase
{
    protected override IPexTestNamer CreateTestNamer(IPexExplorationComponent host)
    {
        return new TestNamer(host);
    }

    class TestNamer : PexExplorationComponentElementBase, IPexTestNamer
    {
        private readonly SafeSet<string> _names;

        public TestNamer(IPexExplorationComponent host) : base(host)
        {
            _names = new SafeSet<string>();
        }

        public bool TryCreateTestName(IPexGeneratedTest test, out string testName)
        {
            var template = ReflectionHelper.EscapeForMetadataName(test.ExplorationName.Method.ShortName);
            testName = MetadataHelper.GetUniqueNumberedName(_names, template);
            _names.Add(testName);
            Debug.WriteLine("*** " + testName + " ***");
            Debug.WriteLine(test.BodyCode);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```